# Reference environment variable in AWS elasticbeanstalk config file

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to get the public ip address for the EC2 instance during AWS elasticbeanstalk environment setup.

Currently I have a .ebextentsions/my.config file where the Tomcat JVM options are set.

I'm trying to set the rmi hostname to the public ip address for the EC2 instance:

```
 - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
   option_name:  "java.rmi.server.hostname"
   value:  "{client_external_IP_addr}"
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: for which purpose ?

Comment: Bira, That snippet is for an aws beanstalk config file. The beanstalk environment is a  Tomcat with Java environment and there are 2 EC2 instances behind an ELB. I'm trying to reference the instance id of the EC2 instance the config file is running on.

Comment: That will be random, depend on the availability ELB automatically create EC2.

Comment: Auto scaling group is responsible for creating instances, but still... I would thing of hazelcast, or something similar, but in that case that should be done other way. @km1 - Can you elaborate more on the topic?

Comment: I would reccomend to create a CNAME usign route 53 and just hardcode the CNAME in the config. You can get reference to attributes of EC2 instance if you created them with Cloud Formation. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can really do that inline, but https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html seems to think you can use GetAtt or Ref to fetch values. Totally untested, but you would have to first define a resource that captures the AWS::EC2::EIP, maybe like so:

```
Resources:
  myIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2:EIP
```

You could then try:

```
- namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
   option_name:  "java.rmi.server.hostname"
   value:  !Ref myIP
```